# How can I get firebase items in descending order in Java / Android

Tags: android, firebase

Let's say I have some data as follow:

```
"teilnehmer" : {
      "ATYFdfNRThzrEC83" : {
        "score" : 2500,
        "teamname" : "Was ist mit Karsten los?"
      },
      "VMT9hp65Tui55J2" : {
        "score" : 12500,
        "teamname" : "Team Zombie.de"
      },
      "dPkdf233dbMjCA2" : {
        "score" : 21635,
        "teamname" : "Bielefeld zwei"
      },
      "U1xTtKJa0wdZ13"  : {
        "score" : 500,
        "teamname"  : "Max der Eugen"
      }.............
```

And this Java Code:

```
    mDatabase.child("rallye").child("teilnehmer").orderByChild("score").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                // teamname, Platzierung, Punkte
                Teilnehmer teilnehmer = new Teilnehmer(((String) dataSnapshot.child("teamname").getValue()), "Platz x", (dataSnapshot.child("score").getValue())+" Punkte");
                teilnehmerList.add(teilnehmer);     // add to recyclerview
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();    // save
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) { }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                //adapter.remove((String) dataSnapshot.child("teamname").getValue());
                //teilnehmerList.remove();
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) { }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}

        });
```

This doesn't work

```
.orderByChild("score")
```

Screenshot here : i.stack.imgur.com/Y8NlW.png

I get the teamname and the teamscore in a Rallygame. But the order is ascending, not descending :/

```
Output:
Teamname ----------- Score
Team Zombie            50
Team xyz               1500
Team foo              16000
```

Wrong order :/

---

And then I have a second question, how can I output the current Position in Ranking?

For example:

My List show something like this:

```
Rank     Teamname      Points
1        "Team 1"       25.000
2        "Team red"     12.000
3        "Team google"   9.500
4        "Team yellow"   1.250
```

My Firebase contain:

```
"ATYFdfNRThzrEC83" : {
            "score" : 2500,
            "teamname" : "Was ist mit Karsten los?"
          },
```

I have only 2 columns, score and teamname

In my first Question i solve the problem with the Order (most Points -> first place)

My layout file:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/teamName"
        android:textColor="@color/teamTitle"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/teamRank"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/teamScore"
        android:textColor="@color/teamScore"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

3 Output TextViews, but only 2 Datacolumns in Firebase.
The Team with the Most points will be on Rank / Place 1 (i dont know the correct english word for my German "Platz n"). Than  Rank 2, Rank 3....

My first Try:

```
int i = 1;
while(dataSnapshot.child("teamname").getValue()) {

Teilnehmer teilnehmer = new Teilnehmer(((String) dataSnapshot.child("teamname").getValue()), "Platz "+i, (dataSnapshot.child("score").getValue())+" Punkte");
                teilnehmerList.add(0,   teilnehmer);     // add to recyclerview: add(0, teilnehmer) gebe in desc aus von 0 zum n. eintrag
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();    // save
i++;
}
```

I would like three ouputs in one row. Teamname, Rank in Ranking and the current score in the Game.

but my while Loop does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this function:

```
@Override
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    // teamname, Platzierung, Punkte
    Teilnehmer teilnehmer = new Teilnehmer(((String) dataSnapshot.child("teamname").getValue()), "Platz x", (dataSnapshot.child("score").getValue())+" Punkte");
    teilnehmerList.add(teilnehmer);     // add to recyclerview
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();    // save
}
```

I assume you are adding to an array list. Instead of adding to the end, add to the beginning because `orderByChild` is working, its in ascending order. Firebase does not support descending order.

```
teilnehmerList.add(0, teilnehmer); // <--- add 0 as 1st parameter
```

Your second question is lacking detail. Create another question.